# How To Fix "Could Not Find A Part Of The Path" Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have lots of different websites that I work on Visual Studio 2012.  Each one is in a subfolder of the same root folder called Websites on our web server, and I have the Y drive on my PC mapped to that share using my own credentials - I'm an Administrator on the web server.  I'm coding in ASP.NET/VB.NET.

Each page of each website has at the top the line:

`<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>`

This line is automatically added by Visual Studio when I create a new page (obviously the page name differs according to the page I'm working on).

In just one of my websites, whenever I open it in Visual Studio, that line is underlined in blue, and holding the cursor over it reveals the error:

`ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not find a part of the path: 'Y:\<websitefoldername>'..`

This only happens with this one website.  Other sites I open are fine, despite having identical Master lines at the start of their pages and being in folders in the same root folder with identical inherited NTFS permissions.

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013 and opening the same project throws the same error.  I've even gone so far as to create a new project, create each page again from scratch and just copy the body of the code of each page from the original troublesome project, hoping that allowing Visual Studio to auto-generate the code for the new pages would fix the problem, but it didn't.

In practice I didn't think the error was much of an issue since the website runs just fine and throws no errors when I build it.  But I have a second issue which is also unique to this website despite the code being common across all of them so I think I need to fix this one before tackling the other.  I'll post a separate question for that one if I can't get to the bottom of it myself.

Incidentally, I've already checked my Web.config file for the line `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />`, as suggested on various sites, but it's not there.

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this error was being caused by a line in my Web.config file:

`<identity impersonate="true" password="password" userName="domain\username"/>`

Commenting it out has fixed the problem and suddenly all my IntelliSense is working properly, the website compiles correctly and so on.  Unfortunately I kinda needed that key so now I'll have to figure out how to get my site working without it!